# When I run the script on a remote server it starts up on the local machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have `nautilus-dropbox` installed package on my remote server.

I connect to the remote server by ssh, then run command:

```
dropbox start
```

And it starts up on my local machine, how it's possible?

Comment: Do you _succeed_ connecting to the remote machine (__and__ running the command there, and not local machine)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I'm really on a remote server.

Comment: I can't believe this. dropbox daemon is an opaque piece of code who does god knows what, but _this_? Care to share command history, with all needed `ps` commands and whatnot?

Comment: Perhaps, this question is a better fit for ServerFault. Pure admin stuff, no programming.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Linux systems use the X11 protocol for most GUI systems.

The X11 server renders the image and accepts mouse and keyboard input.

The application acts as a client and connects to whatever X11 server you tell it to. This is done with an environment variable.

When you connect over SSH, a tunnel is created back to your local X11 server, and the shell spawned by SSH has the environment variable set to point along that tunnel to your local display.

Comment: You are right! And how can i run the script without using DISPLAY environment?

Comment: What would you expect the GUI application to do without anywhere to display the GUI?

Comment: This script can work without GUI. I have found this lines in it:
`GUI_AVAILABLE = os.environ.get("DISPLAY", '')
if GUI_AVAILABLE:
...`